# Let $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a Cauchy sequence in $C[0,1]$. then $\{f_n(x_0)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a Cauchy sequence in $C[0,1]$. Prove for each $x_0\in[0,1]$ the sequence $\{f_n(x_0)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is   Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$

**My work**

Let $\epsilon >0$
As $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ then exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ sucht that if $n,m\geq N$ then $d(f_n,f_m)<\epsilon$

Here I'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: Use the definition of $d(f_n,f_m)$. What does $d(f_n,f_m)<\varepsilon$ mean in terms of the definition?

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa $d(f,g)=sup\{|f(x)-g(x)| :x\in [0,1]\}$ in my definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

How  is the distance $d(f, g)$ in the vector space $\mathcal C[0,1]$ defined?

Comment: $d(f,g)=sup\{|f(x)-g(x)| :x\in [0,1]\}$ in my definition.

Comment: So for each $x \in [0,1]$, one has $\;|f(x)-g(x)|\le d(f,g)$, right?

Comment: $|f_n(x_0)-f_m(x_0)|<sup\{|f_n(x)-f_m(x)| : x\in[0,1]\}<\epsilon$ then $\{f_n(x_0)\}$ is cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$ is correct this Bernard? Thanks for help me (:

Comment: Quite cotrect.. Unrelated: for proper min, max, &c., in maths formulæ, type them code as `\min` or `\max`.